# Are there variables in Clojure sequence comprehensions?

Tags: clojure, list-comprehension, for-comprehension

I'm reading Programming Clojure 2nd edition, and on page 49 it covers Clojure's for loop construct, which it says is actually a sequence comprehension.

The authors suggest the following code:

```
(defn indexed [coll] (map-indexed vector coll))

(defn index-filter [pred col]
  (when pred
    (for [[idx elt] (indexed col) :when (pred elt)] idx)))

(index-filter #{\a} "aba")
(0 2)
```

...is preferable to a Java-based imperative example, and the evidence given is that it "by using higher-order functions...the functional index-of-any avoids all need for variables."

What are "idx", "elt" if they are not variables?  Do they mean variables besides the accumulators?

Also, why #{\a} instead of "a"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. There are no variables in functional languages. Actually, you need distinguish ***variable*** and ***value***. `idx` it's just a name bound to concrete value, and you can not reassign it (*but you can rebound it to another value*).
2. First parameter of function `index-filter` is predicate, that means function that return `true` or `false`. `#{\a}` it's a data structure `set`, but it also can be treated like a function. If you pass element as argument to set function it returns this argument (like *true*) if element exists and nil (like *false*) otherwise. So you can think about this set predicate as anonymous function written in more understandable way `#(contains? #{\a} %)`

Comment: So earlier in the chapter they discuss "vars", i.e. (def a 1).  I guess where I'm confused is the difference between a variable, and an immutable var that's value is changed.  Is this in effect creating idx1, idx2, idx3, etc in memory for each iteration, and when idx is dereferenced it returns the last value idx held?

Comment: you just can not change bound value in scope where it's defined. so for example every your for iteration has exact value of `idx` and you can not simply reassign it like in imperative languages

Comment: Vars are actual memory locations whose contents can be read and written. The bindings in a list comprehension, as in a (let [] ...) expression, are more lexical in nature - you can think of the symbols here as placeholders that get replaced with an actual value when the expression is evaluated.

Comment: Still not really getting this.  If its A. a named pointer to a place in memory, B. has a value, and C. is dynamically changed...how is it not a variable?  If these are really immutable, then I would think they would all be separate locations in memory (and there for have to be garbage collected somehow)

Answer (score 5):

`pred` is a *function* - `#{\a}` is a set containing the character a. In Clojure, a set is a function which returns true if its argument `\a` is contained by it.  You could also use `#(= % \a)` or `(fn [x] (= \a x))`.

As the other answer implies, "no state was created in the making of this example."  `idx` and `elt` function like variables, but are local only to the `for` sequence comprehension, so the code is more compact, not stateful, and arguably clearer (once you're used to sequence comprehensions, at least :-) ) -- perhaps the text is not optimally clear on this point.